# Styling a button and anchor tag with the same css properties not working

Tags: css, forms, button

I have the following CSS to style a button and an anchor tag as they have the same button style but they are in different locations. SO I thought to give them the same CSS so that they would both render exactly the same. However, the `button.enter` has the text pushed down. The first one works fine. It would work with padding:0 but that would affect the first one.
Any ideas?

```css
a.enter, button.enter {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('../img/enter-button_small.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add another style that will reset the padding on the button alone. Some of your css is unrequired as well. `vertical-align:middle;` does nothing in this case for example.

```
a.enter, button.enter {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: url('../img/enter-button_small.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 300px;
}

button.enter {
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but I was looking for the reasons why this happens. It should render the same for both why is the text pushed down when they both share the same CSS properties?

Comment: Buttons, Input (submit) have the text vertically and horizontally aligned as standard in most browsers without you needing to style anything. An `<a>` tag doesn't. Introduce padding to the `<a>` and you get the text where you want. Padding on a button shifts the text off centre.

Comment: Thanks David that was the answer I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention margin and padding as 0 coz button has the default margin and padding.

Add this below code

```
a.enter, button.enter {
text-decoration: none;
background: green url('../img/enter-button_small.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
line-height: 35px;
padding: 8px 0;
text-align: center;
color: white;
margin: 0 auto;
text-shadow: none;
font-size: 16px;
width: 300px;
vertical-align: middle; display:inline-block; padding:0; margin:0; border:none
}​
```

Here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/6Ygc2/